# When I execute git push origin master, why is error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:sshallow/FirstPod.git'

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods, podspec

I am learning to create public cocoapods, I have always encountered this problem,

**This is the step I tried.**

1. **`pod lib create FirstPod`**  (Some files are automatically generated，eg,_Pods,FirstPod.podspec,Example)
2. **Add my files to FirstPd/Classes** (a custom UIView ,include .h and .m)
3. **Modify the podspec file**（ s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0' and s.ios.framework  = 'UIKit'）
4. **`cd FirstPod/Example/`**,then  `pod install`
5. Execute the following code, error when executing `git push origin master`

```
git add -A && git commit -m "Release 0.1.0"

git tag '0.1.1'

git remote add origin git@github.com:sshallow/FirstPod.git

git push --tags

git push origin master
```

[image]

```
pod --version 1.7.5
```

**update:**
I just tried it again according to this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332), and it is still the same mistake! 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to create an *empty* repository, as opposed to one with an initial README.md file

That will help avoiding the error message.

But in your case, if you don't care about said README.md file:

```
git push --force -u origin master
```